# Database design for categories, subcategories and keywords filtered data

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am creating an application that lists local businesses and groups them by category, subcategory and keyword. Here are the rules for how businesses are sorted:

- A business can belong to multiple categories and subcategories
- A business can have multiple keywords
- Not every category has subcategories, but those that do are only two levels deep (category -> subcategory)
- A subcategory can belong to multiple categories

Also worth mentioning is that the client has given me the list of businesses in an excel document which is laid out as such:

- Each category is a separate tab, or page
- Each page contains the list of businesses, their addresses, keywords and subcategories
- The business' subcategories are designated by an 'X' in a column with the subcategory's name

I have been attempting to solve this through pivot tables, but this has lead me to quite a few pivots (category_subcategory, business_keyword, business_category) and I’m afraid that this will have a substantial impact on performance do to the volume of queries that would be made to determine which businesses to show based on a filter.

I think I am on the right track, but I feel that there is a more optimal way to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

If I read all that correctly, these are the tables I think you should make:

businesses
id, name, etc.

keywords
id, word, etc.

categories
id, name, etc.

subcategories
id, name, etc.

categories_subcategories
id, category_id, subcategory_id

businesses_categories
id, business_id, category_id

businesses_subcategories
id, business_id, subcategory_id

businesses_keywords
id, business_id, keyword_id

Answer (score 0):

Proper way would be to have something like this:

1.Business(id (*PK), name,...)
2.Keyword(id (*PK), keyword,...)
3.Category(id(*PK), name, parent_category (*FK),...)
4.Bis_cat(bis_id (*FK), cat_id (*FK),...)
5.Bis_key(bis_id (*FK), keyword_id(*FK),...)

Where (*PK) are primary keys, and (*FK) a foreign keys.

In this model you would have unlimited subcategories, using recursion.  You can also add referential integrities if you want to be 100% sure that you want have any errors but it's a very tight restriction on a db, so if you know how to do it put it in.